# Move resources using Resharper

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

I want to use Resharper's 'Move resource' refactoring but I can't quite figure it out.  I open a .resx file (f7 for view code), open the file structure window, select some resources, click 'Move Resource', and specify a destination resource file that already exists.  It thinks for a bit, asks me to delete the original resx file, but doesn't move them anywhere (it just deletes them).

Am I doing it wrong?  Has anyone successfully used this tool?

Comment: BTW, the 'Move Resource' command works fine.  But I can't 'Move Resource' on many resources at once, I can only 'Move' them.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper 6 or 7? Does this behavior only apply to "Move resource" or other kinds of Move refactoring as well?

Comment: Here's a bug report related to the problem btw: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-325557